# partial view ajax.beginform onsuccess function error not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am working with MVC5. I have a View that call a Partial View.

On Partial View, I have a `Ajax.BeginForm` that `OnSuccess` call a function.

I have an error on execution time saying the function is not finded.

If the funtion is defined in Parent View, it is finded and triggered.

This is my Partial View

```html
@model TableAvivaVoz.Models.UserPasswordView
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Actualizar";
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "exito",
//        OnFailure ="failure",
    };
}
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function exito(result) {
                alert(1);
        }
    </script>
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Users", ajaxOpts, new { id = "FormID" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
"modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Cambio de Contraseña
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success hidden">
                Success! Password Changed.
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.User_id)
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.OldPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Vieja Contraseña" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OldPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Nueva Contraseña" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Repetir Nueva Contraseña" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer visible">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Save</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer hidden">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
}
```

What I am missing to call the function from Partial View.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sections don't work in partials. Don't use sections in partials. Make sure that you place the following section inside your **main view**, not in the partial:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function exito(result) {
                alert(1);
        }
    </script>
}
```

This will guarantee that the corresponding `<script>` tag that defines your `exito` function gets rendered. You can verify this by inspecting the generated markup in your browser.

Comment: OK, that it was happening, i though I have an error. So I can not define my OnSucess method on my ParentView?